# Xamarin.Android : Does a wrappanel exists?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, wrappanel

I need the equivalent of a WrapPanel for my Xamarin.Android test app.

The goal is to put the maximum of things available on one line, and when there is no more space available, to make a new line with that.

In a lot of case, this will help to have my application looking very nicely in horizontal or vertical layout.

How could I have the same behavior on Xamarin for android?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try a gridview:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

The example above is in Java, but it can easily be converted to Xamarin / C#.

Comment: Seems to be the right direction. Currently unable to test it due to some other issues with Xamarin :(: I validate as soon I was able to see it works :)